# error has some invalid arguments when call functiong in dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using  Set_PolicyInfo from dll file that save data entered by user into the database. But when I am trying to call it from C# it is returning an error 'as some invalid arguments'

My Code :

```
         protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            GhicDl.GhicDl gh = new GhicDl.GhicDl();  

            bool flag =  gh.Set_PolicyInfo(Convert.ToString(ComBoxBranchName.SelectedItem.Text),
                         "DEPT_06", 
                         TxtPolicyNo.Text,
                         Convert.ToString(ComBoxPolicyType.SelectedItem.Text),
                         Convert.ToDateTime(TxtPolicyDate.Text),
                         Convert.ToString(ComBoxAccName.SelectedItem.Value), 
                         Convert.ToDouble(TxtPlcyAmt.Text),
                         Convert.ToDouble(TxtIssueFee.Text),
                         Convert.ToDouble(TxtSprvisionFee.Text),
                         Convert.ToDouble (TxtTransFee.Text),  
                         Convert.ToInt16(TxtDiscountPER.Text),   
                         Convert.ToDouble(TxtDiscountAMT.Text),
                         Convert.ToDouble ( TxtTotalAmt.Text),
                         "10.200",
                         Convert.ToDateTime (TextStartDate.Text) ,  
                         Convert.ToDateTime(TxtEndDate.Text), 
                         "A ",
                         "20/04/2012" ,
                         "DEVP");
       }
```

My Method Signature :

```
 Set_PolicyInfo (string bransh , 
                 string DeptCode , 
                 string PLCYNUM , 
                 string PLCYTYP , 
                 datetime plcydate , 
                 string accno ,
                 double plcy_amt , 
                 double Issuefee , 
                 double sprvisinfee , 
                 double Transferfee , 
                 int DiscountPer ,  
                 double DiscountAmount , 
                 double TotalAmount , 
                 double NetAmt , 
                 datetime dateStart , 
                 datetime dateEnd , 
                 char plcyStatus , 
                 datetime date_status , 
                 string crtUser)
```

Comment: What is `gh.Set_PolicyInfo`? What is its method signature?

Comment: Check if you are passing correct number of arguments at correct positions and of correct datatype.

Comment: @captainsac I check it but I didn't find any thing wrong

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I updated my guestion and add method signature

Comment: value for `double Transferfee` is missing

Comment: Error 1:  "A ".. Replace it by 'A'

Comment: Change Convert.ToInt16(TxtDiscountPER.Text) to Convert.ToInt32(TxtDiscountPER.Text)

Comment: Provide proper datetime value instead of string for date_status parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you passed for the parameter `double NetAmt` is "10.200", which is a string. Should be `Convert.ToDecimal("10.200")`

The value you passed for the parameter `char plcyStatus` is "A ", which is a string. Should be `'A'`.

The value you passed for the parameter `datetime date_status` is "20/04/2012", which is a string. Should be `Convert.ToDateTime("20/04/2012")`. This however assumes that you have the proper Culture settings in place.